# Regular Expression. Only a dot

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9_'.-]{2,15})$");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(username);
```

what it should do is:

```
- all letters are allowed
- all digit are allowed
- symbols such as _'- are allowed
```

I would like to add that only a dot is allowed.

```
user.name      ok
use.rna.me     not ok
```

Thank u a lot for the help!

Comment: with {2,15} I mean that username has to be longer than 2 and shorter than 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a *negative-lookahead*

```
    String p = "use.rname";
    System.out.println(p.matches("(?!.*?\\..*?\\..*)([a-zA-Z0-9_'.-]{2,15})"));
```

O/P :

```
"use.rname" ==> true
"use.rname.xyz" ==> false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a lookahead anchored at the start:

```
"^(?=[^.]*\\.[^.]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_'.-]{2,15}$"
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, you can use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (if you do not add the `(?U)` inline modifier or the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag):

```
"^(?=[^.]*\\.[^.]*$)[\\w'.-]{2,15}$"
```

However, *the patterns above will require 1 dot in the string*. **If a dot is not required**, reverse the requirement: fail the match if 2 dots are present:

```
"^(?![^.]*\\.[^.]*\\.)[\\w'.-]{2,15}$"
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^.]*\\.[^.]*\\.)` - negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ characters other than `.` from the start, followed with a `.` and then again 0+ characters other than `.` from the start, followed with a `.` (NOTE that this can be shortened as `(?!(?:[^.]*\\.){2}`).
- `[\\w'.-]{2,15}` - 2 to 15 characters, either a word one (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or
- `.` or a hyphen
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Looks like I am done. Feel free to ping me if anything is unclear or missing. A regex demo is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/iL0rO8/1). Also, I would use `\\A` instead of `^` and `\\z` instead of `$` in the real code. Also, it is worth to note that *though* a hyphen at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped, some people say it is still a good idea to escape it, if other, less regex-savvy developers are going to support the regex in future.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with

```
^(?=.{2,15}$)[\w-']*\.?[\w-']*$
```

First it makes sure the whole expression is 2-15 characters long with a positive look-ahead. Then it matches any number of `word character`s (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`), followed by an **optional** dot, and again followed by any number of `word character`s. The anchors (`^` - start of line, `$` - end of line) ensures nothing else is present.